# What is wrong with this request (Azure management.azure.com API)

Tags: c#, azure, http, httpclient, azure-api-management

I am trying to get this azure API to work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/machinelearning/webservices/createorupdate

The following code runs a GET request which returns successfully (200 OK and return body), but the Put request to the exact same uri at the bottom fails with a 400 "Bad request".

The code inbetween basically just unwraps the json output of the first request and tried to send the same unchanged data in the input format of the PUT on the same uri.

Could anyone help me see why this fails?

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearning/webServices/{serviceName}?api-version=2016-05-01-preview");
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebService>(json);

var requestBody = new RequestBody()
{
    location = f.Location,
    name = f.Name,
    tags = f.Tags,
    properties = f.Properties
};

var jsoncontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody, Formatting.None);
var content = new StringContent(jsoncontent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); //tried simpler things like "{\"location\":\"West Europe\"}" with no result
var response2 = await httpClient.PutAsync($"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearning/webServices/{serviceName}?api-version=2016-05-01-preview", content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
// last line returns a 400 bad request only.
```

And then I use this custom object;

```
private class RequestBody
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public WebServiceProperties properties { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify by placing your azure subscription Id and resource group name and web service name in the placeholders?

Comment: 400 error usually means the request payload has some issues. Would you mind updating your question and include the request body you're sending (essentially value of `jsoncontent`)?

Comment: @Baskar : yes,  Gaurav Mantri : Considering I'm getting it straight from the same service shouldn't it work regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was one of those obvious things.

The ", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()" snippet at the end ruined it. Removing it fixed the issue and it returns 200 OK without it.